# How to debug stand-alone Web services server and client application in java

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, client-server

I Have java client/server web service deploy and running on different port.

How to debug that web services in java (eclipse tools)
we have implement below structure.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jse/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: You can remote debug your application.

Comment: I want to debug that application .. how ?

Comment: So why not continue with tcp ip monitor part for debugging, see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jse/index.html?#N1036E

Comment: I want to debug code wise